# Tensorflow.js: cannot return a promise inside of tidy

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

Load below html file, wait for the first `<textarea>` to fill up, then click on `Check Memory` button. `tf.tidy(main)` function is supposed to clean all tensors instead its throwing an error in the console. The error is because of `async\await`. In my actual code i cannot remove `async\await`. Below is sample code to reproduce the issue.

Please help. Thanks!

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Split data as Training/Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@2.0.0/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="tf.tidy(main)">
  <p>Total memory consumed:</p>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="memory-before"></textarea>
  <br><br>
  <button onclick="showMemory()">Check Memory</button>
  <br><br>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="50" id="memory-after"></textarea>
  <script>
    /**
     * Reading Data form CSV and splitting it into Training and Testing dataset.
     * Program to split dataset in a csv file using TensorFlow tf.split
     */
    async function main() {
      // Import data from a CSV file.
      const houseSalesDataset = tf.data.csv("http://127.0.0.1:8080/dataset/kc_house_data.csv");

      // Extract x and y values to plot.
      let pointsDataset = houseSalesDataset.map(record => ({
        x: record.sqft_living,
        y: record.price
      }));

      let pointsArray = await pointsDataset.toArray();

      // Extract Features (inputs) and store it in a tensor.
      let featureValues = pointsArray.map(point => point.x);
      let featureTensor = tf.tensor2d(featureValues, [featureValues.length, 1]);

      // Extract Labels (output) and store it in a tensor.
      let labelValues = pointsArray.map(points => points.y);
      let labelTensor = tf.tensor2d(labelValues, [labelValues.length, 1]);

      document.getElementById('memory-before').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tf.memory(), null, '\t');
    }

    function showMemory() {
      document.getElementById('memory-after').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tf.memory(), null, '\t');
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Update:

Moved the `tidy` function invocation from `onload` to inside `<script>` tag as shown below but `tidy` is still not cleaning the memory.

```
tf.tidy(() => { main() });
```

Comment: Why don’t you flip the order of how things are processed? You can do `body onload="newFunction()"`, where `newFunction` makes your async call and then only calls `tidy` once it’s finished

Comment: I tried with anonymous function like `tf.tidy(() => { main() });` inside `script` that removes the error but `tidy` is not cleaning the memory.

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: No. Stopped working on it since it was very clear that TensorFlow.js do not support `await` inside tidy. They have their own versions of sync functions for most of the basic operations. We have to refactor our code to avoid using `await` inside tidy until its supported.

Answer (score 1):

i think the solution would be

```
const handelOnloadevent = async()=>{

tf.tidy(await main());
}



<body onload="handelOnloadevent"></body>
```

if `tf.tidy` doesn't accept the **promise** then just resolve the promise before passing it to `tf.tidy`

Comment: pretty sure this doesn't do anything